# Serilog - RollingFile Sink does not roll files based on date and size

Tags: c#, serilog, rollingfilesink

I am using Serilog - RollingFile Sink, but it stores all data in a single file for a day.
In my application, 1 GB log is written in a day. So I want to roll log file on the basis of date and size.

How can I configure RollingFile Sink to roll files based on date and size?

Comment: Serilog does not support rolling when the file reaches a specific size. Rather, if the fileSizeLimitBytes is reached before the end of the day, logging will stop for that day.

Comment: I have the same need and still looking for a solution. The alternative rolling sink posted by Caio does not appear to support multi-threading either. One possible workaround is to have your tool(s) break up the log file at the end or whatever interval you need.

Answer (score 22):

Nowadays Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile package is deprecated in favor of Serilog.Sinks.File (see the github project [readme](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-rollingfile) intro). Serilog.Sinks.File package has been upgraded to support file rolling.
You can use the following Serilog config to enable rolling both by time and size:

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": ["Serilog.Sinks.File"],
    "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
    "WriteTo": [
        {
            "Name": "File",
            "Args": {
                "path": "logs/log.txt",
                "rollingInterval": "Day",
                "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true,
                "fileSizeLimitBytes": "512",
                "retainedFileCountLimit": 3,
                "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog"
            }
        }
    ]
  }
```

Then you will get something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-rollingfile):

> To avoid bringing down apps with runaway disk usage the rolling file
>   sink limits file size to 1GB by default. The limit can be changed or
>   removed using the fileSizeLimitBytes parameter.
>
> ```
> .WriteTo.RollingFile("log-{Date}.txt", fileSizeLimitBytes: null)
> ```

The example shows removing the limit by setting it to `null`.  In your case, set it to an appropriate size.

**UPDATE**

Yes, based on your comment I looked at the source code and it looks like the RollingFileSink's lowest unit of measure is a day so having more than one on the same day seems to be not supported.  However, and I didn't look closely, it looks like the `OpenFile` methods in [RollingFileSink.cs](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-rollingfile/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile/Sinks/RollingFile/RollingFileSink.cs) does something with sequence numbers.  You might want to take a peek and see what that code is doing.

Comment: fileSizeLimitBytes ensures the size of the file. It means after reaching this limit logging will be stopped. New file is not created after reaching this limit.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for this alternative implementation of the RollingFile sink:

> ### Serilog Rolling File Sink (alternative)
>
> This is a rolling file sink that allows you to specify roll over behaviour based on file size.
>   https://github.com/BedeGaming/sinks-rollingfile

Comment: It rolls file on size. 
e.g. if logger is initialized on 12-10-2016, it creates a new file but it uses the same file on 13-10-2016 until the file reaches specified size.

I want to roll file on the basis of both date and size.
I want to create a new file per day and when the file reaches specified  size, a new file should be created with date and no. in the file name. 
e.g. Api-20161012-0002.log

Answer (score 1):

In appsettings.json you should write something like that:

```
{
"Serilog": {

  "Using": ["Serilog.Sinks.File"],
  "MinumumLevel": {
    "Default": "Error",
    "Override": {
      //"Microsoft": "Warning",
      //"System": "Warning",  
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication": "Verbose",
      "WebApplicationLogger1.Startup": "Warning",
      "WebApplicationLogger1.Pages": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "WriteTo": [
    {
      "Name": "RollingFile",
      "Args": {
        "rollingInterval": "Day",  // --> THIS IS THAT YOU NEED
        "pathFormat": "C:\\Logfiles\\File-{Date}.log",
        "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Warning"   
      }
     }
   ],
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution

```
private readonly Serilog.ILogger _logger; //= Log.ForContext( "Name", "Weather" );

public WeatherForecastController() {
  string subPath = Path.Combine( DateTime.Now.ToString( "yyyy" ), DateTime.Now.ToString( "MM" ) ) + $"/{DateTime.Now.ToString("dd")}_Weather";
  _logger = Log.ForContext( "Name", subPath );
}
```

---

```
  .UseSerilog( ( hostingContext, loggerConfiguration ) => loggerConfiguration
    .ReadFrom.Configuration( hostingContext.Configuration )
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .WriteTo.Map(
      "Name",
      "Request",
      ( name, wt ) => {
        if (name == "Request")
          wt.RollingFile( Path.Combine( $"{hostingContext.Configuration["LogPath"]}/{{Date}}-{name}.txt" ) );
        else
          wt.File( $"{hostingContext.Configuration["LogPath"]}/{name}.txt" );
      } )
  );
```

Comment: I get the following:  Error - CS1061 - 'LoggerSinkConfiguration' does not contain a definition for 'Map' and no accessible extension method 'Map' accepting a first argument of type 'LoggerSinkConfiguration' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Where did you specify the size limit before rollover?

Comment: RollingFile is unknown. Can you paste a more complete code sample or include details of any additional packages that are needed?

Comment: builder.Host.UseSerilog( ( hostingContext, loggerConfiguration ) => loggerConfiguration
  .ReadFrom.Configuration( hostingContext.Configuration )
  .Enrich.FromLogContext()
  .WriteTo.Console()
  .WriteTo.Map(
    "Name",
    "Request",
    ( name, wt ) => {
      if (name == "Request")
        wt.File( Path.Combine( $"{hostingContext.Configuration["LogPath"]}/Request/{name}.txt" ), rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day );
      else
        wt.File( $"{hostingContext.Configuration["LogPath"]}/{name}.txt" );
    } )
);

Answer (score 0):

The current version also implements rolling hourly.
That might be another solution to your ploblem.

> {Hour} Creates a file per hour. Filenames use the yyyyMMddHH format.

like:
.WriteTo.RollingFile("log-{Date}.Hour")

Answer (score 0):

My file still doesn't roll and I've followed all the setup instructions. I don't think this simple thing can be so hard to setup, can someone point out what I have wrong?

I have the latest of the following packages installed and my app runs on .Net Core 3.1:

- Serilog.AspNetCore
- Serilog.Enrichers.Environment
- Serilog.Enrichers.Thread
- Serilog.Settings.Configuration
- Serilog.Sinks.Console
- Serilog.Sinks.File
- Serilog.Sinks.RollingFileAlternate

This is my code in Program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    // For Serilog docs refer to https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore
    public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; } = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .Build();

    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
            .CreateLogger();

        try
        {
            Log.Information("Starting web host");
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            return 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Fatal(ex, "Host terminated unexpectedly");
            return 1;
        }
        finally
        {
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseSerilog()
            //add configiration calling the method below
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration(SetupConfiguration)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }

    public static void SetupConfiguration(WebHostBuilderContext ctx, IConfigurationBuilder builder)
    {
        //removing the default configuration options
        builder.Sources.Clear();

        builder.SetBasePath(ctx.HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath)
               .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
               .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{ctx.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
               .AddXmlFile("app.config");
    }
}
```

And here's my appsettings.config part:

```
"Serilog": {
"Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
"MinimumLevel": "Information",
"WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "RollingFileAlternate",
    "Args": { "path": "../Logs/MyLog_dev.log" },
    "RollingInterval": "RollingInterval.Day",
    "RetainedFileCountLimit": 20,
    "fileSizeLimitBytes": 1000000,
    "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true
  }
],
"Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId" ],
```