# Serilog `rollOnFileSizeLimit` doesn't work with configuration file

Tags: c#, .net-core, serilog

When configure `Serilog` by configuration file(with nuget package `Serilog.Settings.Configuration`), it doesn't create rolling log file when size limit is reached.

As suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39821560/serilog-rollingfile-sink-does-not-roll-files-based-on-date-and-size) and [this issue](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration/issues/184#issue-451936680), I'm using `Serlog.Sinks.File` (version 4.0.0), but rolling file is not created.

This is my serilog config file `appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [
      "Serilog.Sinks.File",
      "Serilog.Sinks.Console"
    ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "%LogPath%\\Logs\\log.txt",
          "rollOnFileSizeLimit ": true,
          "retainedFileCountLimit ": 20,
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "fileSizeLimitBytes": 10000
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Console"
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName" ],
    "Destructure": [
    ],
    "Properties": {
    }
  }
}
```

This is the code I tell `Serilog` to read from the configuration:

```cs
//previous code ommited... 
.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, configApp) =>
                {
                    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("LogPath", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
                    configApp.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false);

                    configApp.AddEnvironmentVariables();
                    configApp.AddCommandLine(args);
                })
                .UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) =>
                {
                    loggerConfiguration
                        .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration);
                         .WriteTo.Console();
                })
```

When file size reaches 10KB, it stops growing, and no new log file is created.
BTW, rolling by day is still working.

I also verified by configuring `Serilog` by code, and it works, so I think it's not related to the sink...

This is the code which works

```cs
 .UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) =>
                {
                    loggerConfiguration.MinimumLevel.Debug()
                            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
                            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                            .WriteTo.File(path: Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Logs", "log.txt"),
                                rollOnFileSizeLimit: true,
                                retainedFileCountLimit: 20,
                                rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
                                fileSizeLimitBytes: 10000
                                )
                            .WriteTo.Console();
                })
```

So how could I make Serilog create rolling file when file size is reached by configuration file?

Comment: Why is `"fileSizeLimitBytes": "10000"` 10000 in quotes?

Comment: @FaizanHussainRabbani tks. I've tested removing the quotes, but still the same issue. Also I guess that `serilog` could recognize number in quotes, because it take effects..

Answer (score 10):

I downloaded and debugged with the `Serilog.Settings.Configuration` source code, and found that I made a stupid mistake here.
The no-effect parameter name in the config file has an extra space.

```json
"rollOnFileSizeLimit ": true,
"retainedFileCountLimit ": 20,
```

should be

```json
"rollOnFileSizeLimit": true,
"retainedFileCountLimit": 20,
```

After correcting this, all things work.

I assume maybe the project maybe should trim spaces before matching the keys...

Comment: Admit it, it was to confuse ChatGPT, uh?

Comment: Somehow I made this exact same mistake. We must have copied our initial configuration from the same source.

Answer (score -1):

Be careful while typing.  Previously you add a semicolon, and it don't compile this way:

```
loggerConfiguration
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration)**;**
    .WriteTo.Console();
```

Comment: This information doesn't answer the question and should rather be noted as a comment or omitted. The idea being that all "answers" are potentially an answer to the initial question, discussion and clarification occurs in the comments. If you have another StackExchange you can link them to get over the reputation requirement to make a comment. With that said, thank you for taking the time to assist :)